# product measure of weak (-*-) converging signed measure is weak-(*)-converging?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Assume that we have a sequence of signed measures $\mu_n$ on $[0,1]$ that converge weak(-*) to $\mu$, that means:

For all continuous and bounded functions $f:[0,1] \rightarrow R$ we have
$\int_0^1 f(x) \mu_n(dx) \rightarrow \int_0^1 f(x) \mu(dx)$.

**Question**

Does then also the product measure on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ $\mu_n \otimes \mu_n$ weak(-*-)converge to $\mu \otimes \mu$?

i.e: for all continuous and bounded functions $f:[0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow R$ do we have
$\int_{[0,1] \times [0,1]} f(x,y) \mu_n(dx)\otimes \mu_n(dy) \rightarrow \int_{[0,1] \times [0,1]} f(x) \mu(dx)\otimes \mu(dy)$.

**Alternative Question**

If this is not true for all such $f$ is it for example true for $f(x,y)=f(x-y)$? (or/and for $f$ being smooth)

**Remark**

This is true if $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ are probability measures. But is this also true for signed measures?

Comment: *Hint.* Any signed measure is a difference of two finite positive measures. (Or, depending on definition, it may be written as a difference of two positive measures of which at most one is infinite.)

Comment: How does this help? If $\mu^n = \mu^n_+ - \mu^n_-$ then (I think) it is not even clear that $\mu^n_+ \rightarrow \mu_+$ weakly for example...

Comment: You are right, that is a very delicate part and deserves a thorough justification... I missed that point.

Comment: @mimi: Not only is it not clear, it is in general false.

Answer (score 1):

Prove it first for $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ then for a finite linear combinations of such functions. Then use the fact that finite linear combinations of such functions are dense in $C([0,1]^2)$ (which follows from Weierstrass theorem).

Comment: I think this answer does NOT solve the problem:
Using your answer, for $f \in C([0,1]^2)$, lets call $f_k$ the sequence of finite linear combinations of such functions converging to $f$. Then for each $k$: $\int f_k(x,y) \mu^n\mu^n \rightarrow \int f_k(x,y) \mu\mu$ AND for each $n$ $\int f_k(x,y) \mu^n\mu^n \rightarrow \int f(x,y) \mu^n\mu^n$. 
BUT the speed of the last convergence depends on $n$ and the speed of the first convergence depends on $k$... Hence one might NOT find a diagonal sequence of $k,n$ ... Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: or another way to write it: $|\int f \mu^n \mu^n - \int f \mu \mu| \leq |\int f \mu^n \mu^n - \int f_k \mu^n \mu^n|
+|\int f_k \mu^n \mu^n - \int f_k \mu \mu|
+|\int f_k \mu \mu - \int f \mu \mu|$.
Now the last integral is no problem, but to bound the first integral by $\epsilon$ one needs that $k$ is big enough for given $n$ and to bound the second integral one needs that $n$ is big enough for given $k$... Hence there might not be a combination that satisfies both... Or is your idea different from that?

Comment: Assume that the convergence holds for any $g\in A\subset C([0,1]^2)$ where $A$ is dense. Take any $f\in C([0,1]^2)$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose $g\in A$ such that $\sup|f-g|<\epsilon$ then $|\int f\mu^n\mu^n-\int f\mu\mu|\leq |\int f\mu^n\mu^n-\int g\mu^n\mu^n|+|\int g\mu^n\mu^n-\int g\mu\mu|+|\int g\mu\mu-\int f\mu\mu|\leq \epsilon(|\mu^n\mu^n|+|\mu\mu|)+|\int g\mu^n\mu^n-\int g\mu\mu|$. Now weakly star convergent sequence is bounded (Banach-Steinhaus theorem) so ...